# Are there any difference between WPF Coded UI Tests and WinForms Coded UI Tests?

Tags: wpf, winforms, coded-ui-tests

Is WPF Coded UI Test has the same issues as the WinForms Coded UI Test has?
Are there any difference between WPF Coded UI Tests and WinForms Coded UI Tests?

Are there the same pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coded UI tests do not know or care how the application being tested was written. Coded UI tests use the MSAA or UIA interfaces made available by the UI controls of the application. The UI controls need to be written to support MSAA or UIA and that is not easy! The UI controls in the Microsoft libraries for WPF and Windows Forms support MSAA or UIA. Some of the older UI control libraries, such as MFC, have limited support. Custom control may or may not support MSAA or UIA and hence may of may not support Coded UI. Third Party libraries of UI Controls often supply custom controls that build on top of the Microsoft UI controls, hence they may or may not support MSAA or UIA. For Third Party controls you should examine their documentation or ask their suppliers about what level of Coded UI support they provide.

This page shows the "Supported Configurations and Platforms for Coded UI Tests and Action Recordings"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx

This page is the best overview I have found for Third Party support of custom controls for Coded UI, although it has not been updated in over two years
http://www.edsquared.com/2011/02/01/ThirdParty+Support+For+Visual+Studio+Coded+UI+Testing.aspx

Comment: Our teamlead said that he developed his own small framework for WinForms UI testing. He said that he did it in two days and his framework came up much more handy than Microsoft's Coded UI Test. Microsoft's Coded UI Test produces a bit brittle and unreadable code in comparison to his small framework. Now, my task is to work out with Coded UI Test with WPF and to understand framework's abilities. Can you add something? And can you advice a couple of resources to grasp the Coded UI Test within WPF?

Comment: One of the problem our teamlead faced with WinForms Coded UI Test is that sometimes (quiet often) it was very slow; tests sometimes came to a condition of a stupor before performing a click on a button.

Comment: My team handcodes coded UI tests to bypass the "brittle unreadable" auto code problem that comes with using the recording functionality of coded ui. Using coded ui as a c# library opens up testing while still being mostly application-under-test agnostic besides for determining if MSAA or web based. See: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4590771%2Fhand-coding-a-coded-ui-test&ei=8zgnUq_yIsuosQTAx4GICw&usg=AFQjCNFfjNVrgfszyGB9PXO61VgwIYRPHA&sig2=1f4OVjqvavVX5dxBuWZm0Q&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cWc

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI do not care about the type of the application.It uses MSSA and UIA interface to get the control.The difference we can see the in coding like HTMLcontrol ,WinControl,WPF control.
Identification of control concept is same for all the application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is good to answer questions but your answer here just repeats information already given in other answers. Hence your answer is not useful. (Also, your answer wrongly states *"MSSA"* and it has poor punctuation and spacing.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between web application and WPF application in coded UI.
In web application you will have control of HTML
And in WPF it is control of WPF.Both HTML and WAF resides in UITESTCONTROL. Few coding concept you might need to know for WPF automation like virtual child and cointiner class